# Proving an elementary matrix theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

**Question:**
I am seeking assistance in proving the following theorem related to elementary matrix:

**Theorem:** Let $P$ be the $m\times m$ matrix that is obtained from the identity matrix $I_m$ by permuting its rows in some ways. Then for any $m\times n$ matrix $A$ the matrix $PA$ is the matrix  obtained from $A$ by permuting its rows in precisely the same way.

While I understand the concept of the theorem, I am unsure how to determine the specific elements of the matrix $P$. Could someone please guide me on how to construct such a matrix $P$ based on the given row permutation? Any step-by-step approach or illustrative example would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

---

**Proof:** Let $A=[a_{ij}]_{m\times n},\quad P=[p_{ij}]_{m\times m},\quad I_m=[\delta_{ij}]_{m\times m}$
$$[PA]_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{m}p_{ik}a_{kj}=?$$

Comment: If $\sigma:\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\to\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$  is the permutation, then you can write $P=[\delta_{\sigma(i),j}]$

Comment: So we have $[PA]_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{m}\delta_{\sigma(i),k}a_{kj}=a_{\sigma(i),j}$. And the proof is finished and correct?

Comment: This looks correct. If you realize how $P$ looks like and that left-multiplication of *any* matrix $A$ with $P$ permutes $A$'s rows in one and the same way then there is not much to prove. In particular you don't have to write out a sum representing a matrix multiplication.